# How to consolidate two branches into one both locally and remotely

Tags: git

I have a remote repository with 2 branches.

- main
- master

Main is the default, and it's completely empty. All my changes are being committed and pushed to master. I just want to change everything over (locally and remotely) so that I'm working in the default new standard "main".

Which commands should I run to make this happen?

tldr;
Locally I am working in master, and main doesn't exist. Remotely both branches exist, the default is main and all my files are pushed to master. I want to change it all over so I'm just working in "main" both locally and remotely.

Comment: Unless you're the only one modifying the repo, you shouldn't be working in the main branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First say

```
git checkout master
git branch -M main
```

to rename your local `master` as `main`. Now push, perhaps pulling first, to make the remote `master` look the same as your branch new local `master`. Finally, delete the remote `master`.

Comment: And please read https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Comment: Thank you for that link! Very helpful...